# Error in Creating Line from Points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arctoolbox, data-management

I am trying to create coastline of an area by joining about 20,000 points using Data Management Tool "Points to Line" in ArcGIS 10.1. But it seems that the inbuilt algorithm is not recognizing the order in which points have to be connected which results in creating some crazy disordered line. Is there a way to get it right? I have added the screenshots.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a field with the order they are supposed to be in, then input that field into the "sort field" option.